# Rails Escaping JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I'm working on an external API.

They want JSON as a string for a GET request in a query param.

The problem with Ruby is that it treats JSON as a string and escapes quotes, so we end up sending:

`"{\"api_key\":\"9e4b33422adb-3832c7-41379-b2f31-8fc295aefb8c8\",\"ip\":\"184.61.23.239\"}`

Instead of `{"api_key":"9e4b33422adb-3832c7-41379-b2f31-8fc295aefb8c8","ip":"184.61.23.239"}` as their system is expecting.

Any idea the best way to handle formatting our JSON to match their criteria?

Comment: It definitely sends like that? I thought that that escaping was just when displaying the stringified JSON in the console, though if you `puts` the same code you have above it looks as you want it (i.e. it doesn't _actually_ contain the backslashes when it matters).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `JSON.parse`, i.e.,

```
JSON.parse("{\"api_key\":\"9e4b33422adb-3832c7-41379-b2f31-8fc295aefb8c8\",\"ip\":\"184.61.23.239\"}")
```

returns

```
{"api_key" => "9e4b33422adb-3832c7-41379-b2f31-8fc295aefb8c8","ip" => "184.61.23.239"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is using gem 'oj'. I prefer to use this gem, because it so fast and good performance.

Using with oj like this:

```
j = Oj.load("{\"api_key\":\"9e4b33422adb-3832c7-41379-b2f31-8fc295aefb8c8\",\"ip\":\"184.61.23.239\"}")
```

It will be:

```
=> {"api_key"=>"9e4b33422adb-3832c7-41379-b2f31-8fc295aefb8c8", "ip"=>"184.61.23.239"}
```

Comment: Any idea what the performance improvement for this actually is?

Comment: @TomHammond Please visit https://github.com/ohler55/oj and read about Performance Comparisons. Thanks.